# Is possible to override Xamarin Forms control properties from native custom renderer?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I have implemented native iOS custom renderer for Entry Xamarin Forms control where changed some properties like BackgroundColor.

I need to override some properties from custom renderer. Is this possible?

Comment: This question needs more details, to be able to give a useful answer. Give a more complete example of what you mean by "change property like BackgroundColor"?  Are you wanting to implement new properties that aren't already defined in Entry class?  Are you wanting to use the BackgroundColor that was defined in XAML, in a way different than Entry uses it by default?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is hard to understand (what you exactly want to do).
In my XF-app, I use an Editor-Control on a page.
As the default-fontsize on iOS is to small, I have implemented a custom-render to set a larger font (especially and only) for iOS.
You also can override other properties (similar to he fontsize in the example).

In XF add:

```
public class MG_Editor : Editor // Interface to specific Renderer
{
// only placeholder for interface
}
```

In the **iOS**-project add a class like "iOS_Specific.cs":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
//
// additionall usings 
//
using MatrixGuide; // your namespace
using MatrixGuide.iOS; // your namespace.iOS
//
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
//
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MG_Editor), typeof(EditorCustomRenderer))]

namespace MatrixGuide.iOS

{
    public class EditorCustomRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {   // perform initial setup
                // lets get a reference to the native control
                var nativeTextView = (UITextView)Control;
                // do whatever you want to the UITextField here!
                nativeTextView.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(18);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the XF-Code (E.G. on a page) create the control:

```
var EditorxxYourWishedNamexx = new MG_Editor();
```

So, for Android and WP the standard Editor-control is used, whereby for iOS the custom-implementation (with the larger font) is used. 
Notes:
- MatrixGuide is the namespace of my app.
- Instead of EditorxxYourWishedNamexx you can take a name you like.
- Similar you also can implement custom renderers for the other platforms.